# Use separation of variables to find the displacement of the string for $t > 0.$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

My question is:

Consider a semi-infinite string stretched between $2$ fixed points. Let $u(x, t)$ be the displacement of a string, at position $x$ and time $t.$

We describe the wave equation by:
$$u(x, t) = G(x − ct) + F(x + ct)$$
for arbitrary functions $G(z)$ and $F(z).$

The string is subject to boundary conditions: $$u(0, t) = u(1, t) = 0 ,\: t > 0.$$

The string has an initial displacement $u(x, 0) = f(x), x ∈ (0, 1)$ and is initially at rest.

**Use separation of variables to find the displacement of the string for** $\textbf{t > 0.}$

Using the identity $\sin \theta \cos \phi =\frac{1}{2}(\sin(\theta − \phi) + sin(\theta + \phi))$ and the Sturm Liouville boundary value problem, rewrite your answer in the same form as
$$u(x, t) = \frac{1}{2}(\overset{ˆ}{f}(x − ct) + \overset{ˆ}{f}(x + ct))$$

I'm really not sure how to find the displacement in this question so any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You may solve the problem

$$u_{tt} = c^2 u_{xx}$$ in $0 < x < 1$ subject to the initial and (homogeneous) Dirichlet boundary conditions given above.

Use separation of variables and let $u = P(t)Q(x)$. Note that the problems for $P$ and $Q$ are second order ODEs:

$$ P''/(c^2 P) = Q''/Q = \lambda$$

Where $\lambda$ is a separation constant. Note that the only nontrivial functions satisfying $Q(0) = Q(1) = 0$ are

$$ Q_n(x) = \sin(n \pi x), \quad n = 1, 2, \ldots$$

where I have made $|\lambda| = n^2 \pi^2$ (why?). Now, let $u$ be a linear combination of $Q_n(x)$ and $P_n(t)$.

---

*Addendum*

So we know that any combination of sines will be a solution of the equation for $P$. We know care about the temporal dependence by seeking solutions $u$ in the most general form

$$ u = \sum_{n=1}^\infty P_n(t) Q_n(x), $$

because there are infinitely many *eigenfunctions* $Q_n$. From the PDE, one has

$$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty (Q_n P''_n - c^2 Q''_n P_n) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty Q_n [ P''_n + (n \pi c)^2 P_n ] = 0$$

Now, leverage the orthogonality properties of $Q_n$ to find an equation for $P_n(t)$ (in this case is trivial), to be solved with initial conditions [I think there's a typo in your question]:

\begin{align} 
& u = 0 \implies P(0) = 0 \\
& u_t = f(x) \implies P'_n(0) = \frac{\int^1_0 Q_n(x) f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x}{ \int^1_0 Q^2_n(x) f(x)  }
\end{align}

---

Can you take it from here?

Comment: We already got given the eigenvalues of  $λ=n^2\pi^2$. Ive been trying for a few hours and still cant seem to make any progress. Is there a chance for a bit more help??

Comment: @Tristan Please, see my edit